# Curl throws error (3) with variable but not with manually written URL

Tags: bash, curl

I am communicating with HDFS using curl. Procedure to interact with HDFS via webhdfs is two steps and I receive a url from a first curl command:

```
create_request=$(curl -i -X PUT "http:/somewhere:50070/webhdfs/v1/${path}?op=CREATE")

destination=$(echo "$create_request" | grep Location | cut -d " " -f 2)
```

Using the `destination` variable, I can upload my file with the following:

```
curl -i -X PUT -T $local_file_path "$destination"
```

However, the above commands throws :

> curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Using the exact same command but changing `$destination` bby the URL it contains (writting it manually) works file.

Why do I have this problem and how to solve this ?

PS: `$destination` does contain the data: `http://datanode:50075/webhdfs/v1/path/test/file.jar?op=CREATE&namenoderpcaddress=cluster&overwrite=false`

---

Edit: Quoting

```
path="mypath"
local_file_path="untitled.txt"

create_request="$(curl -i -X PUT "http://ip:50070/webhdfs/v1/${path}?op=CREATE")"

destination="$(echo "$create_request" | grep "Location"| cut -d ' ' -f 2)"

curl -i -X PUT -T "$local_file_path" "$destination"
```

Gives the same error message.

Comment: `"$local_file_path"` use quotes around variables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: @MichalH Quoting does not solve the problem (see edit)

Comment: @0stone0 Quoting all the strings does not solve the problem, see edit (why can't we "ping" more than one user at a time in comments... ?)

Comment: @FlorianCastelain Then the destination must be wrong, maybe contains a trailing space?

Comment: if you `echo ">$destination<"` does it really contain exactly the same as when you type it in (between `>` and `<`)? Not a single character extra?

Comment: @MichalH A trailing space is probably not it (`cut -d ' ' -f 2` shouldn't leave any spaces at all).

Comment: @TedLyngmo true, also Florian you can try `diff <(echo "$destination") <(echo "actual_url")`.

Comment: The result of the diff command is: 1c1
``< http://url:50075/webhdfs/v1/user/florian_castelain/test/?op=CREATE&namenoderpcaddress=cluster&overwrite=false
---
> http://url:50075/webhdfs/v1/user/florian_castelain/test/?op=CREATE&namenoderpcaddress=cluster&overwrite=false``

Url is correct, but I am not able to check what has changed...
@MichalH

Comment: @FlorianCastelain Great - that log explains it. I made an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a `\r` (carriage return) back in `$destination`. You can remove it with `tr -d '\r'`

```
destination=$(echo "$create_request" | grep Location | cut -d " " -f 2 | tr -d '\r')
```

Comment: Wow. Right. Did you understand that from the diff result ? Is carriage return the only possible reason that the diff says there is a difference while not showing it ?

Comment: @FlorianCastelain I actually misread the output :-) I thought the diff output was the raw output from my `>$destination<` suggestion, but yes, it explains it because `>dest<` would show up as `<dest` if there's a `\r` at the end of the string.